# Plotting a PDF with discrete non-integer values

Tags: plotting

I can plot the PDF of a continuous distribution like so

```
d0 = NormalDistribution[0, 1]
Plot[PDF[d0, x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

I can plot the PDF of a discrete distribution with integer values like so:

```
d1 = PoissonDistribution[2]
DiscretePlot[PDF[d1, x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

But I can't figure out how to plot the PDF of a discrete distribution with non-integer values, like this one:

```
d2 = TransformedDistribution[0.1*x, x \[Distributed] d1]
```

Neither `DiscretePlot[PDF[d2, x], {x, 0, 1}]` nor `Plot[PDF[d2, x], {x, 0, 1}]` works.

New to Mathematica and not a mathematician, go easy on me...

Comment: You can manually define the step in [`DiscretePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html), for example: `DiscretePlot[PDF[d2, x], {x, 0, 5, 1/10}, PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: Thanks. Supposing I didn't know what the step size should be, is there a way to do it without drawing random values and making a histogram from that?

Comment: Though [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) says "It is possible to represent certain discrete random variables as well as random variables involving both a continuous and a discrete part with a generalized probability density function using the Dirac delta function", such a notion makes dire straights only: one cannot use the convolution since the product of the distributions is rarely defined. In most known to me sources the PDF is defined for absolutely continuous random variables only.

Comment: Suppose you have a pmf (probability mass function - which gets around @user64494 's concern) for a discrete random variable.  Can you give an example where you would know the pmf but not the set of values that result in a positive value for the pmf?